# FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Tags: react-native, flipper

Recently I am developing an idea box and this application I'm developing doesn't run in release mode anymore. I did the ./gradlew clean but it didn't solve the problem. No error message in my console. So I opened flipper and I found this error that I can't understand. Can anyone help me ?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.boxidy, PID: 19855
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: (0,r(d[7]).useContext) is not a function. (In '(0,r(d[7]).useContext)(r(d[8]).ImagesContext)', '(0,r(d[7]).useContext)' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in u
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in _
    in Unknown
    in PanGestureHandler
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in _
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in P
    in Unknown
    in RNSScreen
    in _
    in Unknown
    in p
    in Unknown
    in RNSScreenContainer
    in f
    in Unknown
    in D
    in T
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in GestureHandlerRootView
    in Unknown
    in C
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in j
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in C, stack:
u@479:262
wr@77:42102
Hl@77:89853
ja@77:79095
Ba@77:78997
Qa@77:78762
Ia@77:75924
Ia@-1
<unknown>@77:26326
unstable_runWithPriority@142:3806
ht@77:26273
pt@77:26208
Pa@77:73297
pi@77:88605
render@77:95350
exports@339:626
run@336:694
runApplication@336:1753
value@41:3469
<unknown>@41:662
value@41:2459
value@41:634
value@-1

    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

PS : in debug mode I have no error

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?

Comment: Yes, it was an import issue.